# Returning Function in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, function

I have a problem in this code because I am not returning any thing!

It works Just as I want it without returning but when I return it crashes.

Can you please help?

```
Public Function Clear() As Boolean


    'resetting the variuabels to be ready for next Order


    ZYZZ = "0"
    VAT = "0"
    MAX = "0"

    'this code is 3 peices 

    'This is sitting ctrl as a new control
    Dim ctrl As Control = Me.GetNextControl(Me, True)



    '1- is to look for text box and change them to 0 after the button is pressed
    Do
        If TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox Then
            ctrl.Text = "0"
        End If
        ctrl = Me.GetNextControl(ctrl, True)

    Loop Until ctrl Is Nothing


    '2- it clears the list box
    OrderListBox.Items.Clear()

    'And uncheck the check boxes
    LoyalCheckBox.Checked = False
    TakeAwayCheckBox.Checked = False


    'Finally it resets the Price, VAT, Total in the UI 

    Label6.Text = "£" & " " & "0"
    Label7.Text = "£" & " " & "0"
    Label8.Text = "£" & " " & "0"

    'Clearing the array to prepare for next order

    arr.Clear()



End Function
```

Also same problem in this code!

```
Private Function calculate() As Boolean


    '=================================='

    ZYZZ = 0

    For i As Integer = 0 To arr.Count - 1

        ZYZZ = ZYZZ + arr(i)

    Next i

    '=================================='


    '=================================='

    If LoyalCheckBox.Checked = True Then

        CardT = ZYZZ * card

    Else
        CardT = "0"

    End If

    If TakeAwayCheckBox.Checked = True Then

        TAF = ZYZZ * TA


    Else
        TAF = "0"
    End If

    '=================================='

    VAT = ZYZZ * cVAT

    MAX = ZYZZ - (CardT + TAF) + VAT


    Label6.Text = "£" & " " & ZYZZ

    Label7.Text = "£" & " " & VAT

    Label8.Text = "£" & " " & MAX



End Function
```

I have looked up online but I did not understand the methods they are using that's why its better to ask a direct question, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Public Function Clear() As Boolean`

You define the function as a function who will return a boolean value at all times.

But in your code you don't assign a return value at all.

If you don't want to return a value, just change your function name to:
`Public Sub Clear()`

If you want to return a value, you have to do so:

```
Public Function Clear() As Boolean
     return False
End function
```

---

**Return values**

When you create a new function/method, you can choose if you want that function/method to return a value. This is optional but very useful.

Say that you want to write a function that calculates the sum of 2 values. What you would do, is write the function that way that you pass it the 2 values, and that it returns the sum:

```
Public Function SumOfValues(ByVal value1, ByVal value2) As Integer
```

The return-value will be an `integer` as defined with `As Integer`.

Then you do some code-magic, and at the end of your function, you return whatever you want to return, in my example: the sum of the 2 values:

```
Public Function SumOfValues(ByVal value1, ByVal value2) As Integer
    Dim Sum As Integer = Value1 + Value2
    Return Sum
End Function
```

So, now, whenever you want to know the sum of 2 values, you can just do this:

```
Dim answerOfLife As Integer = SumOfValues(21,21)
```

`answerOfLife` will be 42 in this example.

Comment: What does it mean to assign it as a Boolean?

Comment: There you go, answer improved.